# Bike cable type drain stuck down

Tags: bathroom, drain

My bath has a drain that seems to be cable-operated (like bike brakes) and is currently stuck down.

[image]

Like usually you turn the 'too much water' knob to release, but now it just does nothing.
[image]

The mechanism is completely closed so we can't really figure it out. Any solutions that could make it pop back up or are we stuck calling a plumber?

Comment: `pneumatic` means `air powered` ... most bike brakes are cable operated, and so is your drain plug

Comment: get a small suction cup ... use it to pull up the plug

Comment: Tried the suction cup and... it sucked.Plan today is to crazyglue some thing that could give us a good pry and pull.

Comment: Clearly you have access to the back of the tub, Does the top white lever attached to the cable move when the round actuator is turned? Can you get your hand down under the drain and have someone actuate the round knob while you feel to see if the end of the cable is attached or moves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that worked for us is this: We superglued a coat hook to the drain stopper, let it cure for a good 24 hour, and then pulled. I guess something got stuck and was keeping it down because it seems to work just fine now.

Comment: How did you release the hook and clean off the glue?

Comment: Kept it on as of now in case it gets stuck again, but you can remove superglue with nailpolish, I heard.